# Match number 1 and not 10 or 11 using grep or other way

Tags: regex, bash, awk, grep

I have a file with the following content:

```
image_0001.jpg 0
image_1212.jpg 0
image_1324.jpg 1
image_1784.jpg 1
image_7867.jpg 10
image_1919.jpg 11
```

and I want to find a way to get only the line to match the number in the second column:

if i ask for "0" then only get:

```
image_0001.jpg
image_1212.jpg
```

if i ask for "1" then only get:

```
image_1324.jpg
image_1784.jpg
```

is there a way to do it using grep or awk? so far when I grep for " 1" i am getting lines from 10 and 11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use awk.

```
$ awk '$2=="1"{print $1}' file
image_1324.jpg
image_1784.jpg
```

This would print the value of column 1 only if the value of column 2 is exactly `1`.

**OR**

```
$ awk -v var="1" '$2==var{print $1}' file
image_1324.jpg
image_1784.jpg
```

You could pass the value you want to check through `-v` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Use the word boundary `\b`:

```
grep '\b0\b' input
```

To get just the filename, use `cut` for the first column:

```
grep '\b0\b' input | cut -f1 -d' '
```

Comment: `\b` is handy (works in GNU grep and BSD grep - don't know about other implementations; _not_ part of POSIX, however). However, the OP wants to output _filenames only_, not whole lines.

Answer (score 1):

**[Avinash Raj's `awk` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29079013/45375)  is probably the better choice for the task at hand**, but **if you do want to use `grep`** *and* you're using ***GNU* `grep`**, you can try this:

```
grep -Po '^.+(?= 0$)' in  # this looks for '0'
```

- `-P` turns on support for PCREs (Perl-compatible regular expressions)
- `-o` only outputs the *matching* part of each line
- `(?= 0$)` uses a lookahead assertion to match `0` at the end of the line; since it's an *assertion*, it won't be included in the match, so only the filename is printed.

If you have **BSD grep** (e.g., on OSX), where `-P` and therefore lookahead assertions are not available, use [choroba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29079150/45375) to extract the filename in a separate step using `cut`.